# Download composer packages before install

Tags: php, composer-php, package

I want to force to `composer` to download all packages before to install it and to speedup the dependencies installation on projects.

On production environment, I don't want to wait to packages download, it must be installed from cache.

Something like:

```
$> composer download-install # Currently not exists
$> composer install # Install from previously cached packages.
```

There are any composer option to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: If you have a composer.lock file and the vendor folder then it won't download anything each time you run `composer install` so this should be pretty quick.

Comment: I haven't vendor folder into repository, for me is not a good idea. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: You don't put the `vendor` directory in the repository. You should copy Composer's cache to your server, make sure you have `composer.lock`, and then run `composer install`. The other way is to archive your working build with vendor directory that's ready for production then unarchive it on the target servers.

Answer (score 4):

There's a composer package that does exactly that!

Require it globally like this:

`$ composer global require hirak/prestissimo`

Then just a regular composer install will prefetch all the packages first and then install them as if they're from cache.

`$ composer install`

Read more at https://github.com/hirak/prestissimo

Comment: Thanks :) Anyway I will to look to a more native/without dependencies solution.